# How I can call twice the same WebMethods? (Ajax Control Tool Kit)

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

By using only one function, but to use the two only works the first.
I can not this be? I have to do another same WebMethod to operate the two?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_1" runat="server" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static"  />
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd_1" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" TargetControlID="ddl_1"
     Category="Test" PromptText="--Selecct--" BehaviorID="Test"
     ServicePath="/WebService/Catalogs.asmx" ServiceMethod="LoadMethod" LoadingText="Loading..." />

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_2" runat="server" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static"  />
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd_2" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" TargetControlID="ddl_2"
     Category="Test" PromptText="--Selecct--" BehaviorID="Test"
     ServicePath="/WebService/Catalogs.asmx" ServiceMethod="LoadMethod" LoadingText="Loading..." />
```

NOTE: the two CascadingDropDown are independent

I need two diferent dropdownlist with same data becouse one is for the customer and the other is for company, anyway This control (CascadingDorpDown) can call the same webmethos?

How I can call twice the same WebMethods?

thanks in advances!

Comment: did you consider using `ObjectDataSource` to load data and then simply binding them to the `CascadingDropDown`?

Comment: this two dropdownlist filter to other dropdown list

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_1" runat="server" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static"  />



<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd_1" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" TargetControlID="ddl_1"
 Category="Test" PromptText="--Selecct--" BehaviorID="Test"
 ServicePath="/WebService/Catalogs.asmx" ServiceMethod="LoadMethod1" LoadingText="Loading..." />


<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_2" runat="server" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static"  />


<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd_2" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" TargetControlID="ddl_2"
 Category="Test" PromptText="--Selecct--" BehaviorID="Test"
 ServicePath="/WebService/Catalogs.asmx" ServiceMethod="LoadMethod2" LoadingText="Loading..." />
```

call with two method as `ServiceMethod="LoadMethod1"` next as `ServiceMethod="LoadMethod2"`

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Proven, Ajax CascadingDropDown Control Tool Kit can Load the same WebMethod.

My mistake was that I had the same ID for the property BehaviorID

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_1" runat="server" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static"  />
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd_1" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" TargetControlID="ddl_1"
 Category="Test" PromptText="--Selecct--" **BehaviorID="Test_1"**
 ServicePath="/WebService/Catalogs.asmx" ServiceMethod="LoadMethod" LoadingText="Loading..." />

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_2" runat="server" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static"  />
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cdd_2" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" TargetControlID="ddl_2"
 Category="Test" PromptText="--Selecct--" **BehaviorID="Test_2"**
 ServicePath="/WebService/Catalogs.asmx" ServiceMethod="LoadMethod" LoadingText="Loading..." />
```